# Triangle - Rectangle Intersection in 2D

Tags: 2d, intersection, actionscript

I had previously asked [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8294/triangle-plane-intersection-in-3d-space) for 3D but now I changed my strategy and would like to do the intersection in 2D.

The Rectangle is axis aligned and will always be in a fixed position, and has a constant shape and size, basically I want to clip the red areas of the triangles that extend outside the bounds of the rectangle. 
The triangles could be in any position, shape or size, I my code I have a loop where I check the triangles one by one, however I am still clueless about the math.

I have identified 5 cases of triangle rectangle intersection as shown here.[image: Triangle Rectangle Intersections]

How do I find the intersection points of the triangle and the rectangle?

Comment: You should possibly have this pic copyrighted!

Comment: The picture is not complete. Take e.g. the top left green polygon: it has 5 edges and doesn't include the corner of the rectangle. You can also draw a very similar triangle which does contain the corner of the rectangle, in which case the intersection has 4 edges. Similarly, the big triangle crosses opposite sides of the rectangle, but you can also draw a rectangle which crosses adjacent sides of the rectangle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Sutherland-Hodgman polygon clipping algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sutherland%E2%80%93Hodgman) should work just fine for triangle vs. rectangle clipping. You'll find some more information about clipping algorithms [here](http://books.google.ch/books?id=fGX8yC-4vXUC&pg=PA84&lpg=PA84#v=onepage&q&f=false). Or just search for "Sutherland Hodgman clipping".

Comment: would I get the coordinates of the new generated polygon from the algorithm? What would be the speed I have to perform clipping on a large number of triangles?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "coordinates of the new generated polygon"... you'll get the clipped polygons. AFAIK Sutherland Hodgman is a very fast clipping algorithm but has some flaws (especially with concave polygons). But speed is relative.

Comment: I mean I the green areas in the figure above, I needed the coordinates for those. As far as concave polygons are concerned I wonder what they mean would the triangles be considered as concave polygons?

Comment: Yeah sure. You'll get all the coordinates of the polygons that are inside your rectangle. A triangle is convex, so there's no problem there. This is concave: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave

Comment: Found another excellent link to the Sutherland-Hodgman http://www.sunshine2k.de/stuff/Java/SutherlandHodgman/SutherlandHodgman.html . Now I have 2 options, one by zacharmarz and the one that you suggested.

Comment: Good link, and it even comes with source-code. For line vs. rectangle clipping, consider the Cohen-Sutherland algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%E2%80%93Sutherland). This is the algorithm that is being used in the source-code (from your link) to find line-rectangle intersections.

Answer (score 1):

I think CGAL i too robust for such simple task. And Sutherland Hodgman clipping is usefull, when you have general polygon. But you have axis aligned box and you should make use of it.

So my opinion:

First case: Triangle and box are intersecting. You can figure it out by line-line intersection test (for example this: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Line-LineIntersection.html but you can google it in many ways - also look at EDIT2 at the end of this answer). You make line from every edge of box and every edge of triangle. Then you find intersection of all combinations (there are 12 cases <- 3 (triangle) x 4 (box) edges).

If you find intersection point (IP), test, if IP lies between two vertices of triangle or somewhere else on line (created from triangle edge). If IP lies between vertices, then test, if IP's x and y coordinates lie in box x and y intervals (it's axis aligned) - it's green case on picture. If IP doesn't lie in both of it's intervals, then it's red case on picture. 
[image: intersections]

After this test, you should have several vertices, which define your new polygon created from triangle.

//EDIT: Oh. I forget, you have to take also every vertex from triangle for your new polygon, which lies in box (on picture there are two such vertices).

If no edge-edge intersection is found, you have to check two other cases:

Second case: Whole rectangle lies in triangle - your new points from triangle are just vertices of box.

Third case: Whole triangle is in box. Take original triangle as result.

I hope, this can work. It's not tested. Maybe you can use some heuristic and avoid of testing all possible edge-edge combinations.

//EDIT2: You should also make use of axis aligned box in line-line intersection test - just find y coordinate with given x constant (in case of vertical box edge) or find x coordinate with given y constant (in case of horizontal edge).

Comment: Seems to be good idea! I wonder how fast is it though, any speed optimizations you can think of? I also found http://sebleedelisle.com/2009/05/super-fast-trianglerectangle-intersection-test/ and http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/pointinpoly/default.html don't know if I could build up something on these lines.

Comment: Btw are you some kind of wizard in intersection math, you also answered my 3D question didn't you?

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't understand the edit 2 that you posted.

Answer (score 0):

You may find the answer to your question here on [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140070/compute-union-of-two-arbitrary-shapes)

They suggest using [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Kernel_23_ref/Function_intersection.html) which is a C++ library for Geometric Algorithms.  You could also use C++'s [Boost.Geometry](http://geometrylibrary.geodan.nl/sets.html) for a solution as well.

Comment: I'm using a much dumber language(actionscript) and possibly I may not have the liberty of using these geometric algorithms. Possibly I might need to port them.

Comment: @Kevin, sorry, you didn't specify actionscript in the question.