# How do you find the collision between 3D boxes and 3D QUAD face meshes?

Tags: collision-detection, 3d, mathematics, graphics

I have an axis aligned bounding boxes for 3D object collision, but I have a complex 3d mesh that's divided into 3d faces so I want to check for bounding boxes and collision with the faces of that object.

I know that this might cost efficiency since there are more faces to check, but I can fix the efficiency by only checking certain faces, which I think would give me a more accurate collision test than just using a bounding box for this complex object and an efficient check utilizing certain faces that more likely to collide.

However, I don't know the math to check 3d boxes and 3d faces, so I want to know how to create a collision test for this situation.

Comment: "but I have a complex 3d mesh that's divided into 2d faces"
Those are not 2D faces, those are just 3D faces.
"I know that this might cost efficiency since there are more faces to check"
It doesn't cost more because that's how it's supposed to be.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Triangle-Plane intersection in 3D space](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8294/triangle-plane-intersection-in-3d-space)

Comment: you're right, but how do you check 3d faces with AABB. i'll edit my question

Comment: they're quad faces though

Comment: Quads are just 2 triangles. If you don't care about the intersection details, you can just check if one of the triangle vertices are inside the AABB. If you want the intersection details (the points of the intersection), then you break the quads into triangles and use the algorithm in http://geomalgorithms.com/a06-_intersect-2.html#Triangle-Plane

Comment: There's a potential ambiguity when representing geometry as a quad. If the four vertices aren't exactly co-planar, then we can think of the quad as being folded between a pair of diagonally opposite corners. But there are two different folds possible - one between corners A & C, and one between corners B & D. Both folds give a valid surface with the same edges connecting to neighbouring quads, so we'll need some method to decide which one to use. How should your application address this issue? Can you guarantee your quads are always coplanar, or is there a preferred folding direction?